# Numbers as words

Tags: applied-linguistics

Many readability statistics ask that numbers in the text be pronounced to determine the number of syllables.  What I'm struggling with is if longer numbers are considered one or more than one word. As an example is:

**23,578**

treated as...

**twenty three thousand five hundred seventy eight**

or

**twentythreethousandfivehundredseventyeight**

This is particularly an issue with the SMOG formula that 
requires hyphyenated words to be treated as a single word.

I guess the question is how to convert numeric symbols into written words that is appropriate for readability statistics.  If you have a source (I have searched [EBSCOhost](http://www.ebscohost.com/) for a while to no avail) that backs up what you say please share.

Comment: This is not a linguistics question. There is very interesting work done by, for example, Tania Ionin and Ora Matushansky on the _compositional syntax/semantics_ of number words (http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CG0QFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsemantics.uchicago.edu%2Fkennedy%2Fclasses%2Fw11%2Fcomparatives%2Fdocs%2Fionin-matushansky06.pdf&ei=rEIjT6WfD-L30gHEu8SyCA&usg=AFQjCNHFNjIDMtD3_iK-XIH2eRacVo5mow), but this is clearly totally, sadly irrelevant in the present context.

Comment: @Alexis Wellwood Why?  You may be correct but instead of justifying your conclusion with reasoning you seem to use a string of adjectives and insults.  This comes from natural language processing and discourse analysis, both of which are strongly tied to linguistics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [original 1969 SMOG paper](http://www.harrymclaughlin.com/SMOG_Readability_Formula_G._Harry_McLaughlin_%281969%29.pdf) is pretty clear that the number is treated as a single unit:

> In the 30 selected sentences count every word of three or more
>   syllables. Any string of letters or numerals beginning and ending with
>   a space or punctuation mark should be counted if you can distinguish
>   at least three syllables when you read it aloud in context.

Note that the single number " 23,578 " which begins and ends with a space is indeed polysyllabic when pronounced.

---

EDIT: It depends entirely on which test you choose. Compare Flesch ([Flesch R (1948). "A new readability yardstick". Journal of Applied Psychology 32: 221–233](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/apl/32/3/221/))

> "Count as words numbers or letters separated by space... Count the
>   number of syllables in symbols and figures according to the way they
>   are normally read aloud, e.g two for $ ("dollars") and four for 1918
>   ("nineteen-eighteen"). If a passage contains several or lengthy
>   figures, your estimate will be more accurate if you don't include
>   these figures in your syllable count."

So Flesch says to count a number as one word, but gives you the ability to skip big numbers in your statistics.

But see also Kincaid ([DERIVATION  OF  NEW  READABILITY  FORMULAS  ( AUTOMATED READABILITY  INDEX ,  FOG  COUNT  AND  FLESCH  READING  EASE  FORMULA ) FOR  NAVY  ENLISTED  PERSONNEL](http://digitalcollections.lib.ucf.edu/cdm4/document.php?CISOROOT=/IST&CISOPTR=26301&CISOSHOW=26253))

Recalculated Fog Count:

> The Fog Count treats all numbers, regardless of size, as easy words. 
>   Therefore, **all numbers receive a value of 1**.

Recaculated "Flesch-Kincaid" readability:

> Count as a word any numbers, letters, symbols, groups of letters
>   surrounded by white spaces...For example, **each of the  following count
>   as one word**: couldn't F.O.B. i.e. **32,008**"
>
> With symbols and figures the syllables are known by the way they are
>   normally  pronounced, for example, ¢ (cent) 1 syllable R.F.D. 3
>   syllables **1918 (nineteen eighteen) 4 syllables**

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I read that paper as well but I didn't think it was definitive: He says, _Any string of letters or numerals beginning and ending
with a space or punctuation mark should be counted if you can
distinguish at least three syllables when you read it aloud in context.
If a polysyllabic word is repeated, count each repetition._  I felt that this comment wasn't as clear as your "treated as a single unit".

Comment: I added Flesch and Flesch-Kincaid to show how they interpret the question.

Comment: Thank you Mark that was very clear and great resources.  I'm very appreciative of your time.

Comment: Had thought about years either.  Especially the nineteen eighteen vs. one thousand nine hundred eighteen.  This is being used to create an R package for quantitative discourse analysis and and automated program wouldn't "pronounce" a year correctly (unless I program it to do so).  Thanks again. +1 for the edits.