# Syllable counting acronyms and abbreviations

Tags: applied-linguistics

This question is similar to one I asked earlier about "[Numbers as words](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/numbers-as-words)".

Many readability stats call for counting syllables.  The direction for abbreviations and acronyms seems to be to formulate the syllable count as if though the word(s) were not abbreviated (correct me if I'm wrong on this).  So "DVD" would become digital-video-device and count for 9 syllables.  And 7 "pm" becomes "Post-Meridiem" or 4 syllables.  This does not make sense to me as we don't comprehend pm as post-meridiem or DVD as digital video device.  These acronyms/abbreviations have become words unto themselves.

I'm confused as to how i should proceed with counting these type of words and am looking for clarification on how to treat these words for readability statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Flesch-Kincaid p. 48](http://digitalcollections.lib.ucf.edu/u?/IST,26253) says

> With symbols and figures the syllables are known by the way they are
>   normally  pronounced, for example,
>
> ¢ (cent) 1 syllable
>
> **R.F.D. 3 syllables**
>
> 1918 (nineteen eighteen) 4 syllables

Note they count RFD as 3 syllables, not 7 for Rural Free Delivery.